# Using ArcPy to select joined field

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-joins, select-by-attribute

I have written a script which takes two inputs, intersects them, creates a new field in the output feature class and joins it back to one of the input feature classes. I would then like to select the records in the joined 'Intersect' field that contain the string 'Yes'. Do I need to convert the input from `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)` to a string and use this in the expression? My code is below.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inFeatures = (arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))
outFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
joinField = "Ref"

arcpy.Intersect_analysis(inFeatures, outFeatures)

arcpy.AddField_management(outFeatures, "Intersect", "TEXT", field_length = 
50)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(outFeatures, "Intersect" , '"""Yes"""', 
"PYTHON")

arcpy.AddJoin_management(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), joinField, outFeatures, 
joinField)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), 
"NEW_SELECTION", "\".[Intersect]\" = 'Yes'")
```

Comment: `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)` is already a string. ...AsText()` refers that. Do you get any error?

Comment: Of course, well I'm not sure of the correct syntax - I've tried `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), "NEW_SELECTION", outFeatures + "\".[Intersect]\" = 'Yes'")` but get an invalid expression error

Comment: https://community.esri.com/thread/207431-add-join-and-unusable-header-names-in-arcpy uses `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Parcel_8_Layer2", "ADD_TO_SELECTION", "'Parcel_8.P_OWNER_NM' = 'Parcel_6.P_OWNER_NM'")` But beware to use the correct field delimiters.

Comment: What is the task you are trying to solve? Cant you use spatial join, or Select By Location?